# CipherSweet - not quite getting it

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I'm looking to encrypt some fields in a MySQL table and came across CipherSweet in another post on here. It looks excellent, and I've installed it and got the engine running, but I can't seem to get out of the driveway...
I'm no PHP expert and that's maybe part of the problem - the instructions seem to assume a lot more knowledge than it appears I have.

I have a form that passes data (name, email etc.) that I want to encrypt - my code in that respect works, and I turn them into variables that I have previously been using to write successfully to the database.

```
$UserName = test_input($_POST["UserName"]);
$FirstName = test_input($_POST["FirstName"]);
$LastName = test_input($_POST["LastName"]);
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
```

My question is, how do I then encrypt everything in the row except UserName? I'm using their setup example but don't require any blind indexes at this stage.

```
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Backend\ModernCrypto;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\CipherSweet;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\KeyProvider\StringProvider;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\EncryptedField;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\EncryptedRow;

$provider = new StringProvider(
    // Example key, chosen randomly, hex-encoded:
    'yaddayadda....'
);

$engine = new CipherSweet($provider);
$row = (new EncryptedRow($engine, 'contacts'))
->addTextField('UserName')
->addTextField('FirstName')
->addTextField('LastName')
->addTextField('email');

$prepared = $row->prepareRowForStorage([
    'UserName' => 'User1',
    'FirstName' => 'UserFirstName',
    'LastName' => 'UserLastName',
    'Email' => 'UserEmail'
]);

var_dump($prepared);
```

At this point, I had it working - I assume as the var dump was writing what looked like enctrypted fields to the screen. However, I don't know how to then get the data into the database using a SQL statement. What does the data "look" like? Is 'contacts' after EncryptedRow where I put the name of my table? What does prepareRowForStorage actually do?

As I say, CipherSweet looks awesome, but I just can't quite connect all the dots!

thanks

Calum

Comment: Which fields do you want to encrypt and which do you want to use for lookups? Blind indexes are made for fields that you want to encrypt *and* perform lookups on.

Comment: My plan is to encrypt all but the username field; I don't need any blind lookups as I don't need to search on any of the fields and I want as much data as possible to be encrypted. I'll return all records for each username when I need it.

Comment: So you *do* need to lookup by username then. Just create a blind index for username.

Comment: Even if I add the blind index, I still can't get things working - I don't know how to get the data in the array into the database in the format that CipherSweet returns it. Any ideas on that please?

Comment: Just wondering if anyone is able to help with this please?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how do I then encrypt everything in the row except UserName?

This is kinda hinted at in the documentation about [`EncryptedRow`](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com/php/usage#encryptedrow).

```
<?php
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\BlindIndex;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\CipherSweet;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\CompoundIndex;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\EncryptedRow;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Transformation\LastFourDigits;

/** @var CipherSweet $engine */
// Define two fields (one text, one boolean) that will be encrypted
$row = (new EncryptedRow($engine, 'contacts'))
    ->addTextField('ssn')
    ->addBooleanField('hivstatus');

// Add a normal Blind Index on one field:
$row->addBlindIndex(
    'ssn',
    new BlindIndex(
        'contact_ssn_last_four',
        [new LastFourDigits()],
        32 // 32 bits = 4 bytes
    )
);

// Create/add a compound blind index on multiple fields:
$row->addCompoundIndex(
    (
        new CompoundIndex(
            'contact_ssnlast4_hivstatus',
            ['ssn', 'hivstatus'],
            32, // 32 bits = 4 bytes
            true // fast hash
        )
    )->addTransform('ssn', new LastFourDigits())
);

// Notice: You're passing an entire array at once, not a string
$prepared = $row->prepareRowForStorage([
    'extraneous' => true,
    'ssn' => '123-45-6789',
    'hivstatus' => false
]);

var_dump($prepared);
/*
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["extraneous"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["ssn"]=>
    string(73) "nacl:wVMElYqnHrGB4hU118MTuANZXWHZjbsd0uK2N0Exz72mrV8sLrI_oU94vgsWlWJc84-u"
    ["hivstatus"]=>
    string(61) "nacl:ctWDJBn-NgeWc2mqEWfakvxkG7qCmIKfPpnA7jXHdbZ2CPgnZF0Yzwg="
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["contact_ssn_last_four"]=>
    string(8) "2acbcd1c"
    ["contact_ssnlast4_hivstatus"]=>
    string(8) "cbfd03c0"
  }
}
*/
```

If you notice in the example, the `extraneous` field remains cleartext after encrypting.

So essentially, your `EncryptedRow` object only needs definitions for **the fields you want encrypted**.

Therefore, instead of this:

```
$row = (new EncryptedRow($engine, 'contacts'))
    ->addTextField('UserName')
    ->addTextField('FirstName')
    ->addTextField('LastName')
    ->addTextField('email');
```

You simply need to do this:

```
$row = (new EncryptedRow($engine, 'contacts'))
    ->addTextField('FirstName')
    ->addTextField('LastName')
    ->addTextField('email');
```

Notice the `addTextField('UserName')` has been removed? That's all you have to do.

Note: You can *still index on fields you aren't encrypting*.